# How to customise devise to store user role information in session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, pundit

Currently we are using two separate table for Users and Roles.

I am using **pundit for authorisation and devise for authentication**.

At many places I am doing `current_user.roles` to fetch the roles of the user. Mostly inside pundit policy files.

I want to store the User roles in the session when user logs in. So that I will not query db each time to fetch the roles.

Any quick solution will be greatly appreciated ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Pundit have no options, to pass `session` or other parameter, except `current_user` and checking `entity`, you can use `Rails.cache` instead:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def cached_roles
    Rails.cache.fetch "user.#{self.id}.roles" do
      roles.pluck(:name)
    end
  end

  def clear_cached_roles
    Rails.cache.delete "user.#{self.id}.roles"
  end
end


# app/policies/post_policy.rb
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  # ...

  def admin?
    user.cached_roles.include? 'admin'
  end

  def reader?
    user.cached_roles.include? 'reader'
  end
end
```

To make Devise to cache current roles, you need to override Devise's session_controller

```
# app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super
    current_user.cached_roles
  end

  def destroy
    current_user.clear_cached_roles
    super
  end
end
```

I created this [demo rails application](https://github.com/alexkalinin-stackoverflow-examples/q45113760-user-role-information-in-session), you can play with it: see my solution variant with `Rails.cache` in [rails_cache_solution](https://github.com/alexkalinin-stackoverflow-examples/q45113760-user-role-information-in-session/tree/rails_cache_solution) branch or in pull request.

Also see these files for more details:

- `app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb`
- `spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb`
- `app/policies/post_policy.rb`
- `app/models/user.rb`
- `README.md`